# Can you install a service in system32 or sysWOW64 directory and still pass Windows 7 Software Logo Program?

Tags: windows-7, service

We are trying to certify a program for Windows 7 logo and we have a third party vendor which is providing a service for our application. their documentation and support crew is adamant that the service must be installed and run from the system32 (or sysWOW64 for 64-bit) directory.  The Microsoft documentation states that you should...

> Never write directly to the "Windows" directory and or subdirectories. Use the correct methods for installing files, such as fonts or drivers

our vendor says that services are fine also. Does anyone have any experience with this? Are they correct? Can we logo our app if we put a service in system32?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why a well written service needs to be in the system directory. Just put it in a folder under your app's directory and I'll bet it works fine. If so then I would simply ignore this vendor.

Comment: thanks David, the issue is if it's NOT well written and we go to them for support, they won't support us if we didn't follow their directions...

Comment: I think you should push back hard on this vendor. I doubt you'll get logo installing to system32. I see no reason why a service would be exempt. I don't know for sure. There's nothing in the logo requirements doc saying services get dispensations. But the doc is a bit thin. What did MS say when you asked them? It's kind of moot asking SO, since MS take the decision.

Comment: @David, thanks, we probably will go back to the vendor tougher. I put in a case with Microsoft but they shut me down via phone technical support, they said the logo program only answered queries via email.  I emailed them a week ago, surprise, no answer yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that you will not pass any logo testing with those conditions. You can apply for a waiver, and may be able to get one. But, you'd (actually your vendor) better have good reasons why their service needs to be installed into either of those directories. I cannot think of a reason, but that doesn't make it so.